# Downgraded from Windows 8, and can't get ubuntu installed

Tags: windows-7, windows-8

I got a laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed and I hated it. I installed Ubuntu 12.04 on the entire disk as the only operating system and it worked fine, but I knew at some point I'd need the Windows back.

Anyways, I didn't want to go back to Windows 8, so I disabled the secure boot, enabled the Legacy support, and installed Windows 7, but now I can't install Ubuntu beside it.
I tried Ubuntu 12.04 and 13.10, but when I try to boot the flashdrive it gives the following messages:

```
error: invalid magic number

error: you have to load kernel first
```

Any idea re: how to solve?

Comment: @Braiam sorry, maybe I expressed myself wrong. I am not trying to boot the Ubuntu that was installed... I meant to say that I deleted every single partition on my laptop and installed Windows 7 over the Ubuntu as the only OS so that I could get the Ubuntu installed as used to do before (dual boot), but the live USB does not initiate. It gives me those errors.

Answer (score 1):

install win 7 first. create separate partion for ubuntu from windows. and install ubuntu in the new partition.
http://lifehacker.com/5403100/dual+boot-windows-7-and-ubuntu-in-perfect-harmony

Comment: Windows 7 is already installed, its just that Ubuntu does not boot from USB....

Comment: that's right @wilf

Comment: the problem still sounds like a problem with the USB stick, or the formatting of it. :-s

Comment: must be a usb stick problem. http://www.linuxliveusb.com/en/download

Answer (score 0):

Try using a different USB stick, or formatting it to FAT32, as it won't work with a NTFS filesystem....

There is a guide [here](http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-windows) on creating bootable USB sticks...

Comment: It is FAT32 already, and I created it with Unetbootin, as I always did before.
I'll try this Universal USB Installer, but I don't think it will make any difference :P

Comment: You might as well try something else, like Universal USB Installer, or [Win32DiskImager](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Win32DiskImager),  as Unetbootin does not always work.

Comment: I tried the Universal USB Installer. I don't get those errors anymore, but I can't go any further than the grub page (the grub page does not give me any options other than a prompt to enter commands).

Comment: Try wiping it between imaging *(it should wipe it anyway...)*. You might want to try the `nomodeset` option if you can as well.